# Scheduling artisan command based on condition in crontab

Tags: command-line, cron

I have several artisan commands. The command will send emails (newsletter) to users who have subscribed to my site whenever there are new announcement(s) or tender(s) posted in my site.

So my question is, how do I schedule command in this condition? The command will only run whenever announcement(s)/tender(s) is/are posted in my site.

Running this command below in my crontab definitely schedule the command to run but it will run all the time.

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/pdt-pahang/ && php artisan newsletter:tender >> /dev/null 2>&1


* * * * * cd /var/www/pdt-pahang/ && php artisan newsletter:announcement >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

How do I change the command in my crontab so that it would fit my condition? Any help would be appreciated. I hope I'm not in the wrong place to ask this...

Comment: You should probably trigger it using the website and not the other way around, do you have RSS for your website? I'm guessing that building an RSS update checker in `bash` or `python` will be easier than trying to parse the website and send the updated the other way around.

Comment: Does it really need to run every minute?